# D3 - Binding each data category to g

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to change the data structure of my boxplot.

Currently, I use nest command to group data into category

```
groupedData = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d){ return d.key; })
                .entries(irisData);
```

and make each element at a time e.g. draw vertical lines, draw the boxes, etc. However, I'm looking for a way to bind each category of my data to g's as I illustrate in red boxes below and I will write a function that make plot from there but kinda ran out of idea how to bind data in such the way. Kinda similar to what Mike used it [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502). Unfortunately I don't understand all the magic that happens in his code. So, Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

`svg.selectAll('g').data(data).enter().append('g')`

You can then append other stuff to these group elements that are already bound to the data.

It's hard to help properly since you are only sharing a tiny portion of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It reinforced my idea how it should have been done and helped me solve the issue. The actual problem was I wrapped the axes in "g" as well. So, when I applied the above command it massed up with those "g". As your reply helped me fix my problem, I'll accept it as the correct answer, then.